# Edit Text in SWF File

Tags: c#, .net, adobe, flash

I am wondering the capabilities of the SWF Format.  I have some text in a Flash Video, which is an email address (xyz@somewhere.com) which I would like to write a C# application to edit.  I have the SWF File Format Spec and was wondering if the following is possible:

If I read in the Tag (I am assuming this text is stored as a Static Text Tag, correct me if I am wrong).  Once I found the correct tag for my text I then change the value in the tag and save the SWF file.  Do you see any problems with this approach?

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Yes, almost certainly there is more to this.

First, the swf is most likely compressed and will need decompressing.

Locating the value you need to change should not be too hard, but you will need to change at least one (probably several) field lengths to cater for the change. This in turn will probably require you to parse the rest of the SWF in order to recalculate the lengths of the various blocks that will be altered.

Not for the faint-hearted.